# Check the presence of column name of Oracle table in a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

This is mostly the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76332915/oracle-check-the-presence-of-columns-yes-no-in-a-table)

I would like to get output in a single row instead of multiple rows. If column exists in the interested table, it should output 1, otherwise 0. How can I achieve this?

In the case of table below -

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    ( 
       id           NUMBER(10),
      order_mode     VARCHAR2(8),
      cust_id        NUMBER(6),
      status       NUMBER(2)
   )
```

Expected output -

```
ID, ORDER_MODE, SOME_COL
1, 1, 0
```

or

```
ID, ORDER_MODE, SOME_COL
Yes, Yes, No
```

** UPDATE **

The question is same as I have describe above but need an output in different format. The answer posted in the above question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76332915/oracle-check-the-presence-of-columns-yes-no-in-a-table)) provides the output in two columns format, where first column has the column name and other column contains that the specific column exists or not.

In this question, the output is needed in a single row instead of multiple rows. In my opinion, the solution will be different for the both questions.

Below are the answers to [Littlefoot's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9097906/littlefoot) question.

The meaning of "if column exists" is to know if the specific column is belongs to the table not not. As per the expected output, if "SOME_COL" does not exist in the table, I want to know before executing some other query for the table. That another query might fail if wrong column name is provided.

Comment: I don't understand the question. **a)** What does "if column exists" mean? Is it whether column name ORDER_MODE exists in table ORDERS, or is it whether ORDER_MODE column in table ORDERS contains some values (i.e. isn't empty)? **b)** Table contains 4 columns (ID, ORDER_MODE, CUST_ID, STATUS). Why does expected output contain ID_ORDER_MODE and **SOME_COL**? What is SOME_COL? **c)** If this is the same question as the one whose link you posted, why did you ask another question for the same problem (when you got useful & accepted answers)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle - Check the presence of columns (yes/no) in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76332915/oracle-check-the-presence-of-columns-yes-no-in-a-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM   all_tab_columns
              WHERE  table_name  = 'ORDERS'
              AND    column_name = 'ID'
            )
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END AS id,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM   all_tab_columns
              WHERE  table_name  = 'ORDERS'
              AND    column_name = 'ORDER_MODE'
            )
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END AS order_mode,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM   all_tab_columns
              WHERE  table_name  = 'ORDERS'
              AND    column_name = 'SOME_COL'
            )
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END AS some_col
FROM   DUAL;
```

or:

```sql
WITH columns (column_name) AS (
  SELECT 'ID'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ORDER_MODE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SOME_COL'   FROM DUAL
),
column_exists (column_name, column_exists) AS (
  SELECT c.column_name,
         NVL2(a.column_name, 'YES', 'NO')
  FROM   columns c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN all_tab_columns a
         ON (a.table_name = 'ORDERS' AND a.column_name = c.column_name)
)
SELECT *
FROM   column_exists
       PIVOT (
         MAX(column_exists)
         FOR column_name IN (
           'ID' AS id,
           'ORDER_MODE' AS order_mode,
           'SOME_COL' AS some__col
         )
       )
```

Which both output:

| ID | ORDER_MODE | SOME_COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes | No |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oRVlC9fF)